# Unminifying CSS in PhpStorm

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, minify, unminify

I'm working in PhpStorm 2016.3.2. In my HTML files sometimes found `<style>` tags and minified CSS inside them.

Is it possible to make a shortcut to unminify code inside this tags?

For example, this code:

```
<style>.arrow{fill:none;stroke:#231f20;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:20px;}</style>
```

should looks like this:

```
<style>
.cls-1 {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #231f20;
   stroke-linecap: round;
   stroke-miterlimit: 10;
   stroke-width: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you tried `Cmd` + `Alt` + `L`?

Comment: Yes... It's not working for this.

Comment: Make sure you disable the option: Preferences > Editor > Code Style > CSS > Tab 'Other' > "Keep single-line blocks"  ( http://imgur.com/a/QFnG4 )

Comment: You could use http://jsfiddle.net/. Just copy your css in this and click on "tidy".

Comment: Oh, great. Now it's working. Thanks, Sebastian! =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**To reformat code for a directory, follow these steps:**

1. In the Project tool window, select a module or directory you want to apply your reformatting to.
2. From the main menu, select Code | Reformat Code or press Ctrl+Alt+L.
   Alternatively, in the Project tool window, right-click the directory and from the context menu, select Reformat Code.
3. In the Reformat Code dialog box, specify the necessary options and filters for you reformatting and click Run.

**To reformat code for the current file, follow these steps:**

1. In the editor of the currently opened file, press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L.
2. In the Reformat File dialog, specify options for the reformatting and click Run.